# Android : dexDebug

Tags: android, debugging, android-activity

I tried to start my first AndroidApp. I make my first class without ana specific function oncly simple "hello Word". However I had 14errors that i couldn't find any solution.

Need ur help guys. 
Regards

`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'`.

```
 > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:

 d:\Profiles\fSabil\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output D:\Profiles\fSabil\AndroidStudioProjects\PremiereApp\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=D:\Profiles\fSabil\AndroidStudioProjects\PremiereApp\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt

 Error Code:

 1

 Output:UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
 com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (com/project/test/PremiereApp/BuildConfig) does not match path (com/project/test/premiereapp/BuildConfig.class)
 at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:520)
 at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
 at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
 at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
 at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
 at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
 at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
 at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
 at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:170)
 at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
 at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158
 at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.jav:229)
 at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
 at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
 at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
 at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
 at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
 at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
 at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
 at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
 at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
 at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
 at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
 at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
 at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
 at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

 ...while parsing com/project/test/premiereapp/BuildConfig.class
 UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
 com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (com/project/test/PremiereApp/R$anim) does not match path (com/project/test/premiereapp/R$anim.class)
 at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:520)
 at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
 at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388).
 .
 .
 .
 at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
```